# Replacing values of a column from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hi have a dataframe with 10000+ rows which looks like this -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['110', 'Demand', 2344, 30953], 
                   ['111', 'Supply', 3535, 321312], 
                   ['112', 'Supply', 35345, 2324], 
                   ['113', 'Demand', 24345, 4542], 
                   ['114', 'Supply', 342, 435623]], 
                  columns=['Material', 'Title', '201950', '201951'])
df

Material    Title   201950  201951
110         Demand  2344    30953
111         Supply  3535    321312
112         Supply  35345   2324
113         Demand  24345   4542
114         Supply  342     435623
```

I have another small dataframe with around 4-5 rows that looks like this -

```
extra = pd.DataFrame([['111', 'Supply', 10],
                     ['112', 'Supply', 20],
                     ['114', 'Supply', 30],
                     ['115', 'Supply', 40]],
                    columns=['Material', 'Title', '201950'])
extra
Material    Title   201950
111         Supply    10
112         Supply    20
114         Supply    30
115         Supply    40
```

I want to replace the values in column `201950` in `df` using values from `extra` wherever `Material` and `Title` match, so that the resultant dataframe looks like this-

```
Material    Title   201950  201951
110         Demand   2344   30953
111         Supply     10   321312
112         Supply     20   2324
113         Demand   24345  4542
114         Supply     30   435623
```

I did try merge

```
updated = df.merge(extra, how='left',
                       on=['Material', 'Title'],
                       suffixes=('', '_new'))
new = '201950_new'
updated['201950'] = np.where(pd.notnull(updated[new]), updated[new], updated['201950'])
updated.drop(new, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This gives me the required output.
But I am looking for a more efficient solution. Since the `df` is huge and `extra` has only 4 rows.

Comment: Show us what you tried, then only we can help you. It seems easily solvable using pandas join or merge. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), but first create `MultiIndex` by `Material` and `Title` columns in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df = df.set_index(['Material','Title'])
extra = extra.set_index(['Material','Title'])

df.update(extra)
df = df.astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
  Material   Title  201950  201951
0      110  Demand    2344   30953
1      111  Supply      10  321312
2      112  Supply      20    2324
3      113  Demand   24345    4542
4      114  Supply      30  435623
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
extra.set_index(['Material','Title']).combine_first(df.set_index(['Material','Title'])).dropna().reset_index().astype(object)
```

output:

```
  Material   Title 201950  201951
0      110  Demand   2344   30953
1      111  Supply     10  321312
2      112  Supply     20    2324
3      113  Demand  24345    4542
4      114  Supply     30  435623
```